# Which Pokémon can't be shiny in Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

In generation 6 games, most of the legendary Pokémon found in the main story are coded to never be shiny. Which of the Pokémon obtainable in Sun and Moon are similarly coded to never be shiny, whether they have to be caught or are simply given to the player?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Serebii](http://serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml) this is the list of shiny-locked Pokemon in Sun/Moon:

- Tapu Koko (With the exception of the event Tapu)
- Tapu Lele
- Tapu Bulu
- Tapu Fini
- Cosmog
- Solgaleo
- Lunala
- Nihilego
- Buzzwole
- Pheromosa
- Xurkitree
- Celesteela
- Kartana
- Guzzlord
- Necrozma
- Zygarde

Probably also *Magearna* and *Marshadow* are shiny-locked like other Event-only Legendaries, they are listed in a different table.

Comment: Good find, I have to remember to check Serebii before other sources

Comment: @Angzuril Usually it's a reliable source, like Bulbapedia.

Comment: I've found both to be pretty unreliable regarding the finer details.

Comment: Finer details are hard to figure out, Reddit is probably better in that case, but you'll still find speculations and hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that Solgaleo, Lunala, and  the Ultrabeasts are shiny locked

Secondary sources [here](http://pokemonforever.com/Thread-SUN-MOON-Pokemon-Sun-and-Moon-Guess-who-s-shiny-locked) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/5cm5pm/is_anything_in_sun_and_moon_shiny_locked/d9xitoa/)

Evidence that [Type: Null is not shiny locked](https://twitter.com/13Jhm13/status/801698130764800000)